multer error while compiling typescript project
i am creating api /product/create where i can create product with image and other details. i am using multer with typescript to upload the image. but when i run npm run build i get this error.
node_modules/@types/multer/index.d.ts(46,13): error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'files' must be of type 'FileArray | null | undefined', but here has type '{ [fieldname: string]: File[]; } | File[] | undefined'.


this is the function createProduct controller
export const createProductController = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    upload(req, res, async (err: any) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send({ err: err.message });
        }

        if (!req.body.name || !req.body.price || !req.body.description || !req.file) {
            return res
                .status(400)
                .json({ err: "All fields should be selected - name, price, file" });
        }

        if (isNaN(Number(req.body.price))) {
            return res.status(400).json({ err: "Price must be a number" });
        }

        let productDetails = {
            name: req.body.name,
            price: req.body.price,
            description: req.body.description,
            image: req.file.path,
        };

        try {
            const createdProduct = await Product.create(productDetails);
            return res.status(201).json({ message: "Product created" });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return res.status(500).json({ err: "Error creating product" });
        }
    });
};

multer disk storage config

// Multer disk storage configuration
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req: Request, file: Express.Multer.File, cb: Function) => {
        cb(null, "content"); // Set the destination folder for storing files
    },
    filename: (req: Request, file: Express.Multer.File, cb: Function) => {
        console.log('inside storage');
        cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)); // Generate unique filenames for uploaded files
    }
});


file upload middleware
// Multer file upload middleware configuration
const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: { fileSize: 10000 * 100 }, // Set file size limit (in bytes)
    fileFilter: (req: Request, file: Express.Multer.File, cb: FileFilterCallback) => {
        console.log('inside upload');
        const fileTypes = /jpg|png|mp4|gif/;
        console.log('file', file.mimetype, file.originalname);
        if (fileTypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase())) {
            return cb(null, true); // Accept the file if its extension matches allowed file types
        } else {
            return cb(new Error('Invalid file type'));
        }
    }
}).single('image');

i looked up on google but couldn't find anything. i tried installing latest version version of multer.
i tried to remove the node_modules and install again.
here is json file
"dependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/express-fileupload": "^1.5.0",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.6",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.11.97",
    "@types/node": "^20.12.7",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.5.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.11",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.4.4"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.11" 
  }

